# Pine Script write ATR information on the right top of the chart

Tags: pine-script

I don't know Pine Script, and I have a question for you.
For your opinion is it possible to write some information on right top of the chart?
In details i need to write the ATR Daily, and 30% of ATR Daily. I need AtrDaily of previuos close also if I change timeframe on the graphic.
Could you help me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `table.new` feature to display information on top right in a table and `request.security()` function to request data from different time frames (daily in your example).

Below code will print the daily ATR and 30% of daily ATR on top right of your chart.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My Script", overlay=true)

atr_daily = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", ta.atr(14))
atr_daily_30 = atr_daily * 30 / 100

var testTable = table.new(position = position.top_right, columns = 1, rows = 2, bgcolor = color.yellow, border_width = 1)
if barstate.islast
    table.cell(table_id = testTable, column = 0, row = 0, text = "ATR Daily: " + str.tostring(atr_daily))
    table.cell(table_id = testTable, column = 0, row = 1, text = "ATR Daily (30%): " + str.tostring(atr_daily_30), bgcolor=color.teal)
```

[image]